# What is sum of reciprocal?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Is ${1\over 1}+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots +{1\over n}$ computable? I couldn't find any formulas to find the result. The explanation would be very helpful. Thanks before.

Comment: please remove this queston, look up harmonic series before people starting to downvote for the harmonic series or harminc number for the n'th time

Comment: I wonder who and why did downvote **all** in this question, which is *not* about the harmonic series but about the $\;n$-th partial sum. Both answers btw look pretty nice to me.

Comment: Why do you want a formula? There are useful asymptotic formulas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation.

Comment: @lhf yeah i think it would be useful for the other questions related with this question

Comment: @DonAntonio : Briefly it was me, but then I reverted them.\

Comment: Note that if $n$ is large, then the value is (by Euler-Macluarin) very close to $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}dx + \text{const.} = \log(n) + \text{const.}$

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is the [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Yeah, i've seen that before, but i can't conclude the answer myself, however thanks for the link

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The result is:
$$S=\Psi(n+1)+\gamma$$
where:$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$
For the explanation see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number